# PhantomJS clicks on one element, but does not click on another

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I have a question.
I've been trying to click on an element. This is a fragment of the source code:

```
<a onclick="edit_subj()">Edit topics</a>
<a onclick="create_new('site')">
  <img src="img/new.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" 
   alt="New" title="New site"> Create new site
</a>
```

And when I use PhantomJS and click on higher element:

```
phantomJSDriver.executeScript("edit_subj();");
```

it works,
but when I try to click on another element:

```
phantomJSDriver.executeScript("create_new('site')");
```

I get an error:

```
[ERROR - 2018-01-22T17:12:10.828Z] Session [f6c23730-ff96-11e7-90c5-
5d358d18a7d9] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find 
variable: create_new

:262 in error
[ERROR - 2018-01-22T17:12:10.828Z] Session [f6c23730-ff96-11e7-90c5-
5d358d18a7d9] - page.onError - stack:
onclick (http://WEBSITE_ADDRESS/:156)
dispatchEvent (:0)
U (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():119)
$ (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():108)
$ (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():101)
gh (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():141)
sh (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():152)
(anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():152)
(anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():152)
(anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():153)
```

EDIT: Some people asked for more examples of what I used:

```
WebElement createNewSite = phantomJSDriver
               .findElement(By.id("edit"))
               .findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(1);
createNewSite.click();

new Actions(phantomJSDriver)
.moveToElement(createNewSite)
.moveByOffset(0, 0)
.click()
.perform();

 phantomJSDriver.executeScript("create_new('site')"); 

 ((JavascriptExecutor)phantomJSDriver)
  .executeScript("arguments[0].click();", createNewSite); 

  phantomJSDriver
   .findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[@src='img/new.gif']"))
   .click();

  new Actions(phantomJSDriver)
   .moveToElement(createNewSite).click().perform();
```

Those are all separate examples. Waits do not help - the problem lies in the fact that I can click other a tag, but cannot click the one I need.
All of those examples throw the same error:

```
Can't find  variable: create_new
```

I have really ran out of ideas, I have tried clicking it by tagName, by referencing to the img tag inside the a tag. It is always the same error.
What is worse, it used to work but suddenly a few months back it stopped working. 
Please help me and thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Try to use some waits before running JS.

Comment: Can you share your code trials with `Java` `click()` and error stack trace along with a bit more of the outerHTML for an analysis?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from yout question why you want to use `Javascript` `click()`. To `click()` on the link with `text` as `Create new site` you can use the following line of code :

```
phantomJSDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[@src='img/new.gif']")).click();
```

Comment: As I said, it does not work either way - I cannot click on it and I cannot execute script. Your solution does not help either.

Comment: I fail to understand why you have tagged `Java` and reluctant to use `Java` click(). Update the question with your `Java` `click()` code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: I am not reluctant, please read carefully, I tried this and IT DOES NOT WORK as it throws THE SAME error as when I try to execute script.

Comment: Can we get to see your code trials and error stack trace please?